# Get tags that start with uppercase in Xpath (PHP)

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to get html tags that start with uppercase using DOMDocument in PHP 5.3.

I'm using a php function registered in XPath to test it, but the function is receiving as first parameters tagNames in lowercase.

The xml:

```
 <test>
     <A>Match this</A>
     <b>Dont match this</b>
 </test>
```

The php function:

[registerPhpFunctions - phpDoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php)

```
...
public function isUpper($name) {
    return (bool)preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $name);
}
...
```

Ant this is the Xpath:

```
//*[php:function("\Cdr\Dom\DOMXPath::isUpper", name())]
```

the function **isUpper** receives $name in lowercase so it don't works.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't case sensitive?
2. There is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Load the code as XML and not HTML. The HTML is not case-sensitive.

```
$xmlDoc->loadXML('<html>');
```

instead of:

```
$xmlDoc->loadHTML('<html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this one-liner**:

```
//*[contains('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', substring(name(),1,1))]
```

this selects any element in the XML document, the first character of whose name is contained in the string of all capital letters.

**XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "//*[contains('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', substring(name(),1,1))]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<test>
    <A>Match this</A>
    <b>Dont match this</b>
</test>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (in this case just one) are copied to the output**:

```
<A>Match this</A>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but here you have a hassle-free approach: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

A complete working example (test.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('test.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("isUpper");

function isUpper($name) {
    return (bool)preg_match('/^[A-Z]/', $name);
}

$els = $xpath->query('//*[php:function("isUpper", name())]');

foreach ($els as $el) {
    echo $el->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

test.xml:

```
<test>
    <A>Match this</A>
    <b>Dont match this</b>
</test>
```

Output:

```
lwburk$ php test.php 
Match this
```

Comment: Unrelated, but here you have a hassle-free approach: http://fsockopen.com/php-programming/your-final-stop-for-php-xpath-case-insensitive