# How to register PHP function in XPath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

How can I `register` `PHP` function in `XPATH`? Because `XPATH` does not allows me to use `ends-with()`

Here is one [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5435606/2825534) given by one member but it does not works with.

The code he has used is:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("ends_with");
$nodes = $x->query("//tr[/td/a/img[php:function('ends-with',@id,'_imgProductImage')]"

function ends_with($node, $value){
    return substr($node[0]->nodeValue,-strlen($value))==$value;
}
```

I am using PHP 5.3.9.

Comment: is it `ends_with` or `ends-with`. There's a hyphen in function name

Comment: Your question title is much misleading. Please leave a comment under the (faulty) answer. And as long as you're having that concrete problem, please use http://stackoverflow.com/a/5435487/367456 from there. If you insist on asking that question, please create a self-contained and working example code in your question. The code you've posted so far can not be executed in it's current form.

Comment: What you ask about is also outlined in the PHP manual: http://php.net/domxpath.registerphpfunctions - So you probably should make more clear what your concrete programming question is here. Or is it only that you stumbled over a non-working answer? If so, just downvote the non-working answer (or correct it).

Comment: @gwillie, You're right. But an answer poster has created function with `_` so it's `ends_with`

Comment: Just change the `'ends-with'` inside your xpath to `'ends_with'` and you should be fine. I think that is what @gwillie wanted to say. At least I'd say that is the first thing one should try out as it seems to be the easy spot to fix this.

Comment: @hakre, I also checked with it. but I will check your below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question it looks like a typo, there is no function named `ends-with` therefore I would expect it not to work:

```
//tr[/td/a/img[php:function('ends-with',@id,'_imgProductImage')]
                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead use the right syntax, e.g. the correct function name:

```
//tr[/td/a/img[php:function('ends_with',@id,'_imgProductImage')]
                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Or for example like with the following example:

book.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
 <book>
  <title>PHP Basics</title>
  <author>Jim Smith</author>
  <author>Jane Smith</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>PHP Secrets</title>
  <author>Jenny Smythe</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>XML basics</title>
  <author>Joe Black</author>
 </book>
</books>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('book.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Register the php: namespace (required)
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

// Register PHP functions (no restrictions)
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions();

// Call substr function on the book title
$nodes = $xpath->query('//book[php:functionString("substr", title, 0, 3) = "PHP"]');

echo "Found {$nodes->length} books starting with 'PHP':\n";
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $title  = $node->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $author = $node->getElementsByTagName("author")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo "$title by $author\n";
}
```

As you can see, this example registers all PHP functions including the *existing* `substr()` function.

See [`DOMXPath::registerPHPFunctions`](http://php.net/domxpath.registerphpfunctions) for more information, that is also where the code example has been taken from.

I hope this is helpful, let me know if you still have a question about this.

See as well:

- [How to use preg in php to add html properties (Aug 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3419138/367456)
- [Using Regex in PHP XPath->evaluate (Nov 2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8031377/367456)
- [Get tags that start with uppercase in Xpath (PHP) (Jul 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11286808/367456); in specific [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288208/367456).
- [Get xpath from search result of a specific regex pattern in a bunch of xml files (Mar 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15259746/367456); in specific [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259938/367456).

Comment: I'm appreciating your depth answer :) that you replied it.

Comment: There is function name `ends-with(string1,string2)` in list in [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)

Comment: You are mixing two languages here: There is XPath (which has `ends-with` in version 2.0) and there is PHP (which has `end_with` in your code example). So better not just copy over code and then wonder why it does not work: You need to understand what it does first. And yes, there is `ends-with` in Xpath 2.0, but not by w3schools, but by the authorative sepcification documents which are here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with - Take care when multiple langauges are involved you know which one you're using and what is valid.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I had tried with `ends-with` in XPath. But it's supported in version 2.0. I agree. But an example which I seen has registred PHP function with XPath like you also has done like registreing PHP function throught Xpath. So it was not working that's why I asked. Please don't mind it my answer as rude but just letting you know dear friend :)

Comment: Yes, no problems taken here, and not rude at all. Just hoping you understand that well as when things mix up it can become a bit complicated.

Comment: Perfect ! :) hakre. Working Great. Accepted your answer friend ;)

Comment: And yes. you can change question title and even question to make it more informative so users can clearly get the Idea of question asked and an answer you suggested.

Comment: Using $xpath->registerPHPFunctions(); without restrictions is evil! Someone that has access to your xsl templates can make your system do anything they want!!